# Extract the last two words of a string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract the last two words of a string in vba.

can anyone help me with that one please?

thank you a lot!

Comment: You need to supply some examples of the string, and some example code of what you've tried already

Comment: last two words or characters? if words, Split() is the way to go, but where are they to be returned to? If characters, use Right() function (`myLastTwoCharacters = Right(string,2)`)

Comment: the string il a sentence like: I have many apples. an i would like to get a lastwords = "many apples" so that I can have a msgbox (lastwords) thanks a lot

Comment: `strArr = Split(yourstring)` and `lastword = strArr(ubound(strArr))` and `secondtoLast = strArr(ubound(strArr)-1)`  This last will error if there is only one word so check to make sure there is more than one before using this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub LastTwoWords()
    Dim s As String

    s = "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of the party"
    ary = Split(s, " ")
    MsgBox ary(UBound(ary) - 1)
    MsgBox ary(UBound(ary))
End Sub
```

Comment: Never heard that "fake" sentence before, always used Lorem Ipsum....now I have a new one to use. Also, nice use of array.

Comment: I've never heard of that one before is all I was meaning...I've heard "the lazy brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", and for "fake text", Lorem Ipsum...just neat to see another "teaching" sentence. (To me anyways, I doubt anyone else likes learning such things :P )

Comment: I really want `ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 1 To UBound(arr)): Debug.Print Join(arr)` to work, but it still keeps `Now is` instead of the last two words.

Comment: @BruceWayne I had to look it up myself, I figured something so specific had to have historical meaning.  I enjoyed this little tidbit and now it is stored in my brain.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Exactly! I thought that the statement was a little too political (or something) for an example from Gary's Student, so searched it and found [the Wiki article on "Filler text"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text). ♫ The more you know ♫